# Loop over table field in Element API plugin

Tags: plugin-elementapi, table-field, element

How can I output the rows and values of a table field using the element api plugin?

Where I have entries I do

```
...
$industries = [];
foreach ($entry->industries->all() as $industry) {
  $industries[] = $industry->title;                    
}
...
return [
    'industries' => $industries
];
```

but `->all()` doesn't work in the scenario of a table.

Answer (score 1):

A table field contains a simple array, you can serialize and unserialize it as it is. So there is no custom action required by your side.
Just use it in PHP like every other textual field